# InterruptedIOException when trying to join modded Minecraft server

Tags: java, exception, server

I am trying to join a server in Minecraft 1.16.5 with mods.  Single player works fine, but when I try to join my friends' server, the game crashes after just a few seconds.  The error log is below, which starts with an InterruptedIOException.  This exception happens when an input/output stream gets interrupted, which is probably happening with the server.  Anyone know how to fix this?

```
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM] java.io.InterruptedIOException
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:662)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:140)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.network.ErrorReportingInterceptor.intercept(ErrorReportingInterceptor.java:32)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.network.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:34)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.network.DebugLoggingInterceptor.intercept(DebugLoggingInterceptor.java:43)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.execute(Download.java:312)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.asTypeWithThrow(Download.java:169)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.asType(Download.java:176)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.asType(Download.java:190)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.utils.CurseForgeApi.getProjects(CurseForgeApi.java:283)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.utils.CurseForgeApi.getProjectsAsMap(CurseForgeApi.java:241)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.managers.CurseForgeUpdateManager.checkForUpdates(CurseForgeUpdateManager.java:50)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.Launcher.lambda$checkForExternalPackUpdates$10(Launcher.java:328)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM] java.io.InterruptedIOException
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:662)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:140)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.atlauncher.network.ErrorReportingInterceptor.intercept(ErrorReportingInterceptor.java:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.atlauncher.network.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.atlauncher.network.DebugLoggingInterceptor.intercept(DebugLoggingInterceptor.java:43)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.execute(Download.java:312)
    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.asTypeWithThrow(Download.java:169)
    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.asType(Download.java:176)
    at com.atlauncher.network.Download.asType(Download.java:190)
    at com.atlauncher.utils.CurseForgeApi.getProjects(CurseForgeApi.java:283)
    at com.atlauncher.utils.CurseForgeApi.getProjectsAsMap(CurseForgeApi.java:241)
    at com.atlauncher.managers.CurseForgeUpdateManager.checkForUpdates(CurseForgeUpdateManager.java:50)
    at com.atlauncher.Launcher.lambda$checkForExternalPackUpdates$10(Launcher.java:328)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM] Error trying to delete the directory **USERSDIR**\temp\natives-40465338c95040b28962a52cee755e60
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM] java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: **USERSDIR**\temp\natives-40465338c95040b28962a52cee755e60\SAPIWrapper_x64.dll
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.utils.walker.DeleteDirVisitor.visitFile(DeleteDirVisitor.java:30)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.utils.walker.DeleteDirVisitor.visitFile(DeleteDirVisitor.java:27)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.utils.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:91)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at com.atlauncher.data.Instance.lambda$launch$19(Instance.java:1124)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[06/03/2022 16:21:54 PM] java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: **USERSDIR**\temp\natives-40465338c95040b28962a52cee755e60\SAPIWrapper_x64.dll
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
    at com.atlauncher.utils.walker.DeleteDirVisitor.visitFile(DeleteDirVisitor.java:30)
    at com.atlauncher.utils.walker.DeleteDirVisitor.visitFile(DeleteDirVisitor.java:27)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at com.atlauncher.utils.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:91)
    at com.atlauncher.data.Instance.lambda$launch$19(Instance.java:1124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```